# Getting started with Box2D for iOS

Tags: iphone, box2d

I just want to run any Box2D "Hello World" or test apps.  I've downloaded the source twice (zip file the first time and via svn the second time), followed the build instructions (do stuff w/ cmake, "make", "make install" etc) and don't know where to go from there.  **How do I run the test apps or Hello World apps that come w/ Box2D on my iPhone (or simulator)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be exactly what you want, but it's worth mentioning that [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) works very well with Box2D, and has an example that comes with it.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls

Answer (score 3):

Ok finally got something to work (this was helpful:  http://box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=6580&p=29800&hilit=cmake#p29800)

Anyways here's what I did:

1. get Box2D source like this: "svn checkout http://box2d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/"
2. In the Terminal navigate to "Contributions/Platforms/iPhone"
3. In the Terminal do "cmake -G Xcode"
4. Double click on "iPhoneTestbed.xcodeproj" in the Finder

Now this Xcode project actually builds and will run in the simulator.  There's some cool demos of Box2D physics.  Hope this is helpful :-)